# using drupal sessions during hook_boot

Tags: redirection, sessions, bootstrapping, location

When a user calls the front page of our site we want to check the country from which the user is surfing and redirect the user directly to the country specific front page.

We chose to use the hook_boot() callback to implement this.

Now we have the problem that we want to save the state "is_redirected" into a global variable that will still be available when the redirected page is loading and is calling our hook_boot() again in order to prevent redirect loops.

We thought about using session management, so we loaded the drupal session code with

include_once(DRUPAL_ROOT . '/includes/session.inc');

The question is now, what is the next step after loading session.inc, do we have to call "drupal_session_initialize()", add a custom entry into the superglobal $_SESSION variable and this custom entry + our session will be available after the redirect?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: What version of Drupal?

Comment: Drupal version 7.14

Comment: Why can't you pass is_redirected as a URL parameter, as opposed to using a session? Just curious.

Comment: We solved it in another way: because we're doing the redirect with `drupal_goto()` and the session gets lost when we call `drupal_goto()` we solved it by checking the language of the requested page. If its the front page and if it is not the correct one according to geoip we do a redirect with `drupal_goto()`. If the requested language page and geiop concur we do nothing. So the main task was finding out whether we have a front page to load and what language version of the front page is it.

Answer (score 4):

`hook_boot()` is invoked too early to use the session, as Drupal has not yet initialised the session. Furthermore, [`hook_boot()` has been removed from Drupal 8](http://drupal.org/node/1909596). `hook_init()` is not invoked for cached pages, but there is a trick to avoid the page is cached: Call [drupal_page_is_cacheable(FALSE)](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!bootstrap.inc/function/drupal_page_is_cacheable/7) in `hook_init()`.

The function that actually stores the current page in cache is [drupal_page_set_cache()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/drupal_page_set_cache/7), which contains the following code.

```
  if (drupal_page_is_cacheable()) {
    $cache = (object) array(
      'cid' => $base_root . request_uri(), 
      'data' => array(
        'path' => $_GET['q'], 
        'body' => ob_get_clean(), 
        'title' => drupal_get_title(), 
        'headers' => array(),
      ), 
      'expire' => CACHE_TEMPORARY, 
      'created' => REQUEST_TIME,
    );

    // Restore preferred header names based on the lower-case names returned
    // by drupal_get_http_header().
    $header_names = _drupal_set_preferred_header_name();
    foreach (drupal_get_http_header() as $name_lower => $value) {
      $cache->data['headers'][$header_names[$name_lower]] = $value;
      if ($name_lower == 'expires') {
        // Use the actual timestamp from an Expires header if available.
        $cache->expire = strtotime($value);
      }
    }

    if ($cache->data['body']) {
      if (variable_get('page_compression', TRUE) && extension_loaded('zlib')) {
        $cache->data['body'] = gzencode($cache->data['body'], 9, FORCE_GZIP);
      }
      cache_set($cache->cid, $cache->data, 'cache_page', $cache->expire);
    }
    return $cache;
  }
```

When `drupal_page_is_cacheable()` returns `FALSE`, the page is not cached; `drupal_page_is_cacheable()`, when called without arguments, returns the value of the parameter passed to the function in a previous call.

As `hook_init()` is invoked before `drupal_page_set_cache()`, calling `drupal_page_is_cacheable(FALSE)` causes the current page not to be cached.

I would call `drupal_page_is_cacheable(FALSE)` strictly when necessary, which in you case means when you are sure you need to set `$_SESSION['is_redirected']`.

Notice that a page is served from the cache when there isn't any session enabled. The function called to get the page from cache ([_drupal_bootstrap_page_cache()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!bootstrap.inc/function/_drupal_bootstrap_page_cache/7)) contains the following code.

```
  // If there is no session cookie and cache is enabled (or forced), try
  // to serve a cached page.
  if (!isset($_COOKIE[session_name()]) && $cache_enabled) {
    // …
  }
```

If then you need to clear the cache for the front page, you can use the following code.

```
cache_clear_all(url('<front>', array('absolute' => TRUE)),  'cache_page');
```

The other alternative to `hook_boot()`, and `hook_init()` I can think of is `hook_exit()` which is called also for cached pages. The only reason I would not use it is that it is invoked after the current page is rendered, which means that when you redirect the user to a different page, the user would wait for two different pages to be rendered (the one rendered before the redirect, and the one to which the user is redirected).

If you are going to use `hook_exit()`, you need at least to call `drupal_bootstrap(DRUPAL_BOOTSTRAP_SESSION)`; if then you need specific functions, you need to change bootstrap phase, such as with `drupal_bootstrap(DRUPAL_BOOTSTRAP_FULL)` when you need a function defined from another module.

Remember that with `hook_boot()` you cannot call functions defined from other modules, as they are not yet loaded; you can only use PHP functions, and a very strict number of Drupal functions, which at least includes the functions defined in [bootstrap.inc](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!bootstrap.inc/7).

Answer (score 0):

I have implemented same functionality in one of my sites using init hook instead.

```
function hook_init(){
 if(drupal_is_front_page()){
  $ip = ip_address();
  $cc = geoip_country_code($ip); // From GeoIP Module
  // Now check $cc with countries supported by the site
  if(array_search($cc, $country_specific_sites){
    // $country_specific_sites is an array of countries supported by the site
    // redirect !
  }
 }
}
```

To avoid infinite redirection all conditions is wrapped in `drupal_is_front_page()`. Alternatively you can declare this as a different function and call it from `page-front.tpl.php`

Comment: Does this work when you have caching turned on?

Comment: Yeah it does work

Comment: It shouldn't...`hook_init()` isn't called for cached pages

Comment: Oops ! I believe i had used this module http://drupal.org/project/cacheexclude

Comment: Exactly, we have to solve this before caching, that's why we're using hook_boot().

drupal_is_front_page() is no option for us because we have a multilingual site, with a front page defined for every language. drupal_is_front_page() essentially just does a variable_get('site_frontpage', 'node') which will always return the default language front page.

Comment: Ok, why not use page-front.tpl.php ? in the mean time let me check mobile tools module which does a redirect in hook_boot as well

Comment: OK, using drupal sessions doesn't work for me if I use

    include_once(DRUPAL_ROOT . '/includes/session.inc');
    
    if (!isset($_SESSION)) {
      drupal_session_initialize();
      drupal_session_start();
    }

I'll get my $_SESSION variable but after calling drupal_goto it's empty again.

So my next approach is to analyze the URL whether the correct front page for the country is called, if not, do a drupal_goto to the country specific page.