# Custom PHP code before a site is loaded

Tags: hooks

I need to **execute a few lines of PHP code before a page is rendered**.
Basically what I need to do is to store in a database the user's original http_referer together with an anonymous visitID, and save this visitID in a session.
So the code i need to execute is something like this:

```
if(!isset($_SESSION['lock'])) { // we only want this to run when the user enters the site, not on subsequent pages
   $_SESSION['lock'] = true;
   save_http_referer_in_database();
   $_SESSION['visitID'] = mysql_insert_id(); // gets the id of the last inserted row
}
```

I've found a few solutions but not very convincing.
**UPDATE 16th Oct: I'm making a short summary here as I've edited this post many many times.**

- First, I tried putting the required code at the top of **html.tpl.php**... it works, but *stops running if i enable caching*. Not good. I don't want to disable caching.
- I tried putting the code in the **settings.php and index.php**, but drupal's session aren't initialized yet in there.
- As suggested here, I've tried creating a custom module implementing **hook_boot**, but this solution has weird problems when caching is enabled.
  What happens is that the **save_http_referer_in_database()** function correctly runs the first time, but when the user loads another page, it runs again! All the subsequent page loads don't trigger it again though.
  [This post](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/36945/using-drupal-sessions-during-hook-boot) has some more informations about it.
  [This bug report on Drupal.org](https://drupal.org/node/592482) shows some other bad things that happen with sessions and caching and hook_boot()
- **SOLUTION:** Use cookies instead of sessions.

Regarding @znerol's answer:

- I wouldn't have DB problems anyway because i save visitID and referer in another database, so i manually db_connect() to my database and manually run mysql_query(). Hopefully it's not a bad thing.
- How could exposing the visitID to the user create problems? The visitID is a completely anonymous ID, generated by MySql as the Auto Increment column of the table containing the http_referers. I can't imagine how someone could use this ID to do something 'bad'.
- The reason why I want to do it inside my application, is that I need the visitID to "connect" certain actions on my site to the http_referer (through the visit_id foreign key). So basically i have a structure like this:

VISITS (visitID, http_referer)
EVENTS (eventID, event_description, fk_visitID)

When an event is triggered, I add it to the database by fetching the fk_visitID from the cookie (or session)

I couldn't find a way to accomplish that through AWSTATS (which is installed) or Google Analytics or other similar software.

I didn't know Piwik but thanks to the API it might be fine for what I need, right?

Comment: make sure if you really need to check the session variable before every page load!

Comment: you're right, i've just edited the original question with additional details.

Comment: I think using a separate cookie (i.e do not depend on $_SESSION) would do the trick. Cookie data will be available in any stage in $_COOKIE and just like $_SESSION, it's browser-session based.

Comment: thanks, using cookies is indeed a simple solution that should work fine. I'm just wondering: might this solution be less reliable, as some people disable cookies while almost no one disable sessions?

Comment: There is no `$_SESSION` without a session-cookie. Drupal sets the ini-value [session.use_only_cookies](http://www.php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.use-only-cookies) in [drupal_environment_initialize](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21bootstrap.inc/function/drupal_environment_initialize/7).

Comment: oh good to know! so there's basically no reason at all to use sessions instead of cookies once i'll have a random visitID. Thanks znerol, very helpful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple of answers for this question because there are multiple problems involved.

### 1. $_SESSION and page cache cannot coexist

You probably noted the call to [drupal_bootstrap(DRUPAL_BOOTSTRAP_FULL);](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!bootstrap.inc/function/drupal_bootstrap/7) in `index.php`. This function essentially calls the following functions in exactly that order:

```
// 1. Run settings.php
_drupal_bootstrap_configuration();
// 2. Call `hook_boot` and attempt to deliver page from cache. Exit if successful.
_drupal_bootstrap_page_cache();
// 3. Connect to the database
_drupal_bootstrap_database();
// 4. Load the variables table (think initialize `variable_get`)
_drupal_bootstrap_variables();
// 5. Load the session and populate `$_SESSION`
drupal_session_initialize();
// 6. Invoke `hook_boot` (For pages not served by the cache)
_drupal_bootstrap_page_header();
// 7. Prepare for multilingual sites
drupal_language_initialize();
// 8. Load all modules and build the page
_drupal_bootstrap_full();
```

Note that `_drupal_bootstrap_page_cache` is called before the session is initialized. Therefore when delivering a page from the cache, `$_SESSION` is simply not yet defined when `hook_boot` is called.

Even more important is that `_drupal_bootstrap_page_cache` does not attempt to deliver a page from the cache when it detects a session-cookie on the request.

Page caching is mutually exclusive to having a session open in drupal core.

### 2. Use your own cookie for the visit-ID

As suggested by others, you may set your own cookie to track visits and http_referer. You can use `hook_boot` in this case and implement something like this:

```
if (!isset($_COOKIE['visitid'])) {
    $params = session_get_cookie_params();
    $visitid = save_http_referer_in_database_and_return_visit_id();
    $expire = 0; /* remove when browser window closes */
    setcookie('visitid', $visitid, $expire, $params['path'], $params['domain']);
}
```

Recalling the bootstrapping order, one might argue that the database may not be ready when `hook_boot` is called and therefore `save_http_referer_in_database_and_return_visit_id` would fail. However unless the setting `page_cache_without_database` is set to true in `settings.php`, `_drupal_bootstrap_page_cache` will make sure that the database connection exists before `hook_boot` is called.

The solution presented has the problem that the visit-id will be exposed to the client. That said, it should better be something which is not predictable (i.e. no serial number but some randomly generated unique id for example).

### 3. (Offtopic): Use third party web analytic software

Even the good old [AWStats](http://awstats.sourceforge.net/) is capable of presenting metrics about HTTP referrers with the additional benefit, that no database inserts are necessary for delivering cached pages. Another good option is [Piwik](http://piwik.org/) which also exposes an API where you could fetch exactly the metrics you need.

Comment: thanks a loto, this is a great answer and you helped me to clarify so many doubts! So the cookie is the way to go. I'm editing my original post for a few final questions, I'd love to hear your take on those.

Comment: @Sifro: Regarding `visitid`, it is a bad idea to expose the auto increment. The most banal reason is that you expose your traffic stats to anyone. Your customers/partners/opponents just need to look at the cookie and they now how many visitors you have. Regarding the events, you may want to take a look at piwik [goals](http://piwik.org/docs/tracking-goals-web-analytics/).

Answer (score 5):

[hook_boot](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!hooks!core.php/function/hook_boot) runs on every page, even on cached pages. Implement it in a custom module.

Generally it's better to not require code to run on cached pages, but that's the best option you have, as opposed to hacking index.php. The primary problem I see with depending on hook_boot, is that you open your self up to a very simple denial of service attack. Anyone with curl and a shell can potentially bring your site down with much less resources when caching isn't used well.

One option to consider it relying on javascript to make a call the site via ajax. That way you can save yourself quite a bit of load on the server.

Comment: original post updated... i'm seriously starting to think that i can't have both the custom code AND caching.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you can implement [hook_boot()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_boot/7) in your custom module.

> Perform setup tasks for all page requests.
>
> This hook is run at the beginning of the page request. It is typically
>   used to set up global parameters that are needed later in the request.
>   Perform setup tasks for all page requests.
>
> This hook is run at the beginning of the page request. It is typically
>   used to set up global parameters that are needed later in the request.

Answer (score 0):

I'd use `hook_init` in a custom module.

https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_init/7

Comment: hook_init() will not be invoked on cached pages.

Comment: very true! hopefully he'll have it saved by then, but I'd also suggest using `hook_boot` like everyone else has said.

Answer (score 0):

You can use drupal Rules module.

Create a new rule:

1. add a title
2. React on event "Drupal is initializing"
3. add your condition
4. add your action in php format.

Here is an export of that rule.

```
{ "rules_run_session_query" : {
    "LABEL" : "Run session query",
    "PLUGIN" : "reaction rule",
    "REQUIRES" : [ "php", "rules" ],
    "ON" : { "init" : [] },
    "IF" : [
      { "php_eval" : { "code" : "if ( isset($some_value) ) {\r\nreturn TURE;\r\n} \r\nelse {\r\nreturn FALSE;\r\n}" } }
    ],
    "DO" : [ { "php_eval" : { "code" : "\/\/ Do your query here." } } ]
  }
}
```

Comment: "Drupal is __init__ ializing", is run during hook __init__. Which doesn't solve the problem.