# Opening user session programmatically using headers information

Tags: 7, users, hooks

I'm developing a website with an external user authentication provider. The whole login process is external, that I don't need to worry about. Once a user is logged in, the external provider adds extra data in the request headers (i.e. customer id), that I can use to map an external customer id with a user from the Drupal users table.

Which hook suits the best to open a session and login the user programmatically on each page request? (`hook_boot()` ?)

Answer (score 2):

As the `hook_init()` doesn't works for the cached pages so the alternate option that seems to me is the `hook_boot()` (This hook is run at the beginning of the page request. It is typically used to set up global parameters that are needed later in the request),

**However** the [discussion here on using the session during hook_boot](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/36945/using-drupal-sessions-during-hook-boot) make me feel that **hook_boot() is invoked too early to use the session, as Drupal has not yet initialised the session**.

> There is a trick to avoid the page is cached: Call drupal_page_is_cacheable(FALSE) in hook_init().

Check more here: [using drupal sessions during hook_boot](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/36945/using-drupal-sessions-during-hook-boot)

Comment: Wouldn't that be a bad idea to disable page cache globally on the whole site? What about checking in `hook_boot()` if headers data are available, if yes, set a global variable and disable page cache so that `hook_init()` is called, which handles the login process.

Comment: @MikeVranckx Yeah I agree that would be a more accurate way, so you can use a combination of both to server your purpose